# Links within a list in r markdown

Tags: hyperlink, r-markdown

I have a list of elements and I would like to make some list elements hyperlinks to refer within the part of the same document. Internal referencing works on texts that are a part of a paragraph, but not on list items. Is there any work around for this?

Comment: Please provide some reproducible code of what you tried so far.

Comment: [script](#test1) 
.
.
.
Script {#test1} // Works

-....
-....
- Type (#type)
-...




Type{#type} // Does not work